# Cant figure out how to apply css to menus in my footer

Tags: html, css

im brand new to coding and in a mad rush to get my website finished before i have to put it live in 4 days. im having serious issues with the menus on my site. i used a drag and drop editor to build it and am customizing small parts using the html element tool where i need to. The problem im having is that the editor as far as i can tell only uses one master css file for styling the menus... which means all my menus regardless on "in editor" settings have 15px padding around them. This is a huge issue for my footer which contains TONS of links. I need to find a way to apply css to only the menus in the footer. (there are a few coppies of the master page meaning theres actually a few footers, one for each master page)

sadly as im so new to code i dont really know what the hell it is im doing here.
but in short i just need to be able to make a little piece of css for my footer that i can apply that will only affect the menus in it and no where else

i dont want to paste the code in here as part of this question as i dont really kno what part to look for and what little i have looked into my code would be like 5 pages long or something. so please if you can help me just let me know what to look for or how to find it (im good at using the google chrome inspect tool) so i can paste only whats needed.

just in case it helps heres the current link to my website.

http://sites.simbla.com/fd066dd7-48f1-6002-53ae-f18c93075f27/careersart_art?misc=1475010324849

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you don't have the options to add classes to your editor. Your footer does not use a footer tag, rather another instance of the div with class 'containerHolder'. What you could do (since the footer is the last instance of this class) is to use the css :last-child selector.

Your code would look like:

```
    div.containerHolder:last-child li {
       // css rules here
    }
```

This will only target items inside of your footer.  This is not the greatest method, but possibly the only one since you don't have control or knowledge of the markup itself.  The above example would only target li's inside of your footer.

Comment: i used this as a starting point and kept screwing around with it using some w3schools tuts and google.. finally got it. thanks a bunch... normally id let my webmaster handle this since hes actually knows how to do this stuff but sadly that was kinda out of the question... so.. ya. not the best place for someone whos only an artist and not at all a programmer to be in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on what you are wanting but you can select all the menu items by using `#MP485 ul li` as the selector or if you want the links `#MP485 ul li a` so if you want to edit the padding you can use something like this:

```
#MP485 ul li { 
     padding-bottom: 2px !important; 
}
```

If you use `!important` at the end this should override any other styles.